# May relatives without boarding passes accompany ticketed passengers to the departure gate?

Tags: usa, air-travel, airports

My daughter is 18 years old. She will travel to Doha, Qatar (DOH). I want to make sure she’s safe and walk with her to the gate where she will board the airplane.

I bought two tickets

1. Daughter’s ticket: Fort Smith, AR (FSM) —> Dallas-Fort Worth (DFW) —> DOH
2. My ticket: FSM —> DFW —>FSM

Our FSM —> DFW flights are the same. I want to sit with her waiting for the actual boarding until she physically enters the airplane to DOH.

Question: will I be allowed to walk with my daughter within DFW airport up till the airplane gate to DOH? Or are there any restrictions. Does the boarding gate for DOH reside in an area that only allows people with boarding passes to DOH?

Comment: While the airport codes are unique, it is easier for people reading this if you add the names of the airports and/or their cities/countries in the question. Also helps to avoid the odd miss spelling of a code.

Comment: Airports - American ones at least - are very safe places, certainly no worse than Qatar as a whole.

Comment: Does your daughter actually need or want this level of hand holding? If she is old enough to go to Qatar by herself she is old enough to get on a flight by herself. In certain circumstances one could think you want to be sure she doesn’t skip on a flight to a place she doesn’t want to go to.

Comment: you're going on an airplane round-trip just for that?

Comment: @jcaron yeah big red flag imo

Comment: @ComptonScattering Yeah, this smells like forced marriage.

Answer (score 9):

That should work.

I assume you are arriving on American Airlines and your daughter will depart on Qatar.

Qatar departs from Terminal D and all flights from FSM yesterday arrived at Terminal E (although the morning flight was cancelled).

Fortunately all terminals in DFW are connected airside by the SkyLink train (https://www.dfwairport.com/guide/connect/) So you can exit the plane with your daughter and use the train to get to Terminal D and walk to her departure gate.

Sometimes there are document check points right at the gate but that varies sometimes even from one day to another. Even if there are, you can just wait right outside the gate check point until it's time to board.

Travel tip: make sure you understand all Covid related requirements to enter Doha and that you have all required document available and ready to present. Sometimes you need to show them every step along the way, sometimes no one wants to see anything at all, you just never know.

A 18-year old should have no problems maneuvering this on her own, especially if you walk her through the process up front. You can sit down with her and look at a terminal map or watch a video together: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muxjEz9KFlw
If she is properly prepared she can easily deal with small hiccups herself even if you are not around. My daughter did her first international flight on her own when she was 14 or 15.

**Answer to the general question**

> Are people without boarding passes allowed to see relatives to the air plane gate?

No. Without a boarding pass you will not be allowed into the secure area. Your case is different, since you actually DO have a boarding pass, just not for the same flight. In that case it depends a lot on the specific details, an in particular on the terminal layout. You got lucky since the terminals in DFW have an airside connection.

Comment: It does depend on whether the 18 year old has had the opportunity to mature and learn to travel independent. Allowing her to call the moves while traveling together before she has to do it on her own is one way.

Comment: Companion passes which allow you to enter the secure area with a passenger are a thing in the US. Ask at the check-in counter. I’ve done it to be with either teenage children (but not 18, more like 14) or elderly parents.

Comment: In my culture, an 18 year old is not a child any more. I flew to the US from England when I was 18, and that was in 1970. My mother took me to the bus that went to the airport.

Comment: In my country kids go to school alone from age 10, in some parts of the US you can get arrested if you let your children take the bus aged 15.

Comment: As usual the US is highly inconsistent: accepted age for being a babysitter is 12. So you are trusted with the well being of young children, but  not with walking down the road!

Comment: In the UK, no ages are specified by law for leaving children alone, and for babysitters, but under some circumstances, parents can be prosecuted if any harm comes to their child whilst a babysitter under the age of 16 is supervising.